# Which variable would be $1 in shell?

Tags: bash, shell, sh, zsh

I created a parametrized shell script. As per my understanding, `$0` is the command name, and `$1`, `$2`, etc. are all the parameters that follow. So in the statement

```bash
ls -lhtr
```

This would be the corresponding variable count:

```bash
ls       $0
-lhtr    $1
```

I have also learned, that if you don't want to do the following:

```bash
chmod +x myScript.sh
./myScipt.sh param1 # in this case, "./myScript.sh" is $0 and "param1" is $1
```

You can just run

```bash
sh myScript.sh param1
```

However, in the second example, would `sh` be `$0`? Or would `myScript.sh` be `$0` (according to the source code in myScript.sh)?

Also, what if I aliased

```bash
alias myScript="sh myScript.sh"
```

?

Would `myScript`, `sh`, or `myScript.sh` be `$0`?

Comment: Why not just try it?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk How do you suggest I do that? I am new to shell scripting.

Comment: No, the shell doesn't consider itself to be $0, $0 is the script name.

Comment: You do that by writing `echo '$0 is ' $0` in the script.

Comment: Remember, these variables are being created by the shell, they don't have to correspond directly to `argv[n]`. They're intended to be useful from the script's perspective.

Comment: @Barmar Wait. I am now more confused. As per shell scripting, `echo`'s `$0` should be `echo`, yet somehow it is `bash` in bash, `sh` in sh and `-zsh` in zsh. Why is that? (I know you told me to put it in the script, but I tried it directly on the shell anyways).

Comment: These variables are set when the script starts, they don't change for every command.

Comment: @Barmar So it varies from script to script? How does the interpreter/shell know?

Comment: `$0` is not a positional parameter; it's a *special* parameter whose name suggests "the thing before the first positional parameter" (aka, the command name). It's set automatically by the shell in most cases. One exception is when using the `-c` option, in which case `$0` takes its value from the first argument after the argument to `-c`. E.g., `sh -c 'echo $0; echo $1' myScript foo`

Comment: Why are you tagging this as _bash_ and _zsh_? Your question refers only to _sh_.

Comment: @user1934428 I'm new to shellscripting; I thought it may have had to do with the interpreter of bash and/or zsh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These variables don't change for every command in the script. When you execute

```
sh scriptname foo bar baz
```

The shell receives the parameters from the operating system. In C, its `argv` array will look like:

```
argv[0] = "sh"
argv[1] = "scriptname"
argv[2] = "foo"
argv[3] = "bar"
argv[4] = "baz"
```

It then creates shell variables from this. `argv[0]` isn't put into a shell variable, the rest are put into `$0`, `$1`, `$2`, and so on, so you get:

```
$0 = scriptname
$1 = foo
$2 = bar
$3 = baz
```

The script can update the parameters starting from `$1` using the `set` built-in, and can use the `shift` built-in to remove parameters from the beginning of the argument list (this is often used in loops that process arguments from left to right).

When you write a command like

```
ls "$1"
```

it refers to the arguments to the script, not the arguments on that command line.